# Laravel auth optional field?

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

In laravel auth

**registercontroller.php**

```
protected function create(array $data) 
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'affiliatetoken' =>Str::random(12),
        'affiliate' => $data ['affiliate'],
    ]);
}
```

requires that

> $data ['affiliate']

is defined... what if i want it optional can i send a null instead? the database is nullable maybe somthing like

if `$data ['affiliate']` is defined create, but if not leave `null` or create `0`

Comment: Use `isset($data['affiliate']) ? $data['affiliate'] : null`

Comment: Yes, You can send a null value. If the content in the ```$data['affiliate']``` is ```empty``` or ```null```, if you are using Laravel 5.6 it will automatically return a null. However, your database must have a nullable column in order to do that.

Comment: you can use Laravel array helper for this, just use array_get($data,'affiliate','default Value'); if you don't set the third argument it will set as default

Comment: Just for your info nothing fancy: if you are using any kind of validations before creating a record, then you can use nullable validation rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [data_get](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-data-get) helper:

```
// 3rd argument is what to default to if the key is not set. null by default
'affiliate' => data_get($data, 'affiliate'),
```

@AnkitPatel suggested [array_get](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-array-get) which works too. `data_get` works on both arrays and objects.

Comment: Very useful. Didn't know that before. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
protected function create(array $data) 
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'affiliatetoken' =>Str::random(12),
        'affiliate' => $data ['affiliate'] ?? null, // or 0 "?? operator is equivalent isset()"
    ]);
}
```